# Selection animation doesn't work for Angular (7) Material Tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to implement Angular Material Tabs with routing, everything works fine just that the underline animation doesn't work. It just remains stuck on first tab and disappears after.
I have the animations and default theme installed as suggested here:

[Angular material tab animation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614198/angular-material-tab-animation-doesnt-work)

and used the code as in the Documentation:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
      routerLink="home"
      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
      home
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link
      routerLink="about"
      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
      about
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a mat-tab-link
      routerLink="about"
      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      routerLinkActive="active"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
      about
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
}
```

Comment: still the same... Maybe something else is missing but cannot figure what. Without routing, the animation works

Comment: have you added desired css properties in `active` class?

Comment: What properties do I need to add? The animation should work without any css